# 変数名や関数名を変更した際、vimで置換する方法

Tags: vim, 正規表現

コードを書いていると、最初は`n`とか、いい加減な変数名をつけていたけれど、やっぱり途中で`count`とか、もう少しマシな名前にすりゃよかった、と思うことがあります。

この場合、単純に `s/n/count/g` では、大抵うまくいきません。`print`が`pricountt`になるなど、多くの関係のないものまで、置換されてしまうからです。

例えば、マッチ範囲を限定するvimの正規表現方言の、`\zs`, `\ze` を利用して
`s/(^|\H)\zsn\ze($|\W)/count/g` とすると、前後に英数字があるものはマッチしなくなりますが、これを毎回打つのはあまりに面倒です。

こういった場合に便利な、うまい方法はないでしょうか。

なお、言語仕様により付けられる変数名は変わってきますが、ここではとりあえず「英数字とアンダースコアのみからなる。ただし、1文字目には数字は来ない」ルールに対応できればいいものとします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/\<n\>/`のように`\<`と`\>`を使うと単語の区切りとして認識されます。
どうでしょうか。

Comment: そんなのがあったのですね。ありがとうございます。 http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/pattern.html#/\%3C 「どの文字が単語を構成するかは、オプション 'iskeyword' で設定します」

Answer (score 6):

単語の開始を表す `\<` と単語の終了を表す `\>` を使うと単語検索ができるようです。

でもって、ご質問のような場面では目の前に対象の単語があるでしょうから、そこにカーソルを載せた状態で `*` を押すと前述のメタ文字を使って単語検索が行われます。そしてこのまま `:%s//count/g` と検索文字列を省略して置換することで、今単語検索したものをそのまま置換できます。

1文字目にも数字を許容してしまいますが、まあ多分問題ないように思います。

参考 [Vimの置換コマンドの使い方 | Memo on the Web](http://motw.mods.jp/Vim/substitution.html)